# Como diferencio estos tipos de datos SQL

Tags: sql

No encuentro la diferencia, aunque en todas la búsquedas me dicen lo mismo pero no puedo desglosarlo por completo su significado para entenderlo. Tipos de datos referente a: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms151817.aspx) Oracle.

- NVARCHAR
- VARCHAR2
- VARCHAR

Comment: Que raro que no encuentres la diferencia, ya que la documentación de tu motor de base de datos seguro tiene esta información. A rasgos simples, la diferencia entre `varchar` y `nvarchar` simplemente es el tipo de codificación. `varchar` soporta sólo string no `unicode`, mientras que `nvarchar` soporta caracteres unicode (muchos más caracteres). Por lo mismo, típicamente usa el doble de espacio que `varchar`. `varchar2` (asumiendo Oracle) se comporta exactamente igual a `varchar`

Comment: Por favor agrega el motor de base de datos que estás utilizando

Comment: He cambiado la etiqueta para futuras vistas no sea de confusión la pregunta ni la respuesta.

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda para no caer en especualciones, la edición de las etiquetas la dejaría directamente al OP, todo pareciera indicar que se refiere a Oracle, sin embargo, aún no estamos seguros a qué motor de  base de datos se refiere.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, sin embargo la edición indica Oracle por parte de TripleX

Comment: Oracle SQL Devoloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle los trata agrupados de la siguiente manera en su documentación:

- **CHAR**  : longitud fija
- **VARCHAR2** y **VARCHAR** : longitud variable
- **NCHAR** y **NVARCHAR2** : datos unicode

## CHAR

El tipo de datos `CHAR` almacena **cadenas de caracteres de longitud fija**. Cuando crea una tabla con una columna `CHAR`, debe especificar una longitud de cadena (en bytes o caracteres) **entre 1 y 2000 bytes para el ancho de la columna `CHAR`**. El valor predeterminado es 1 byte.

Oracle garantiza que:

- Cuando inserta o actualiza una fila en la tabla, el valor para la columna CHAR tiene la **longitud fija**.
- Si da un valor más corto, entonces el valor se rellena en blanco a la longitud fija.
- Si un valor es demasiado grande, Oracle Database devuelve un error.

La base de datos Oracle **compara los valores de `CHAR` utilizando la semántica de comparación rellenada en blanco**.

## VARCHAR2

El tipo de datos `VARCHAR2` **almacena cadenas de caracteres de longitud variable**. Cuando crea una tabla con una columna `VARCHAR2`, especifica una longitud de **cadena máxima (en bytes o caracteres) entre 1 y 4000 bytes** para la columna `VARCHAR2`. Para cada fila, Oracle Database almacena cada valor en la columna como un campo de longitud variable a menos que un valor exceda la longitud máxima de la columna, en cuyo caso Oracle Database devuelve un error. El uso de `VARCHAR2` y `VARCHAR` permite ahorrar espacio en la tabla.

Por ejemplo, suponga que declara una columna `VARCHAR2` con un tamaño máximo de 50 caracteres. En un conjunto de caracteres de un solo byte, si sólo se dan 10 caracteres para el valor de columna `VARCHAR2` en una fila particular, la columna de la fila **almacena sólo los 10 caracteres (10 bytes) y no 50**.

Oracle Database **compara los valores de `VARCHAR2` usando semántica de comparación no soportada**.

## VARCHAR

El tipo de datos `VARCHAR` es sinónimo del tipo de datos VARCHAR2. **Para evitar posibles cambios de comportamiento, utilice siempre el tipo de datos `VARCHAR2` para almacenar cadenas de caracteres de longitud variable**.

## En cuanto a la semántica de longitud para los tipos de datos de caracteres

El soporte de globalización permite el uso de varios conjuntos de caracteres para los tipos de datos de caracteres. El soporte de globalización le permite procesar datos de caracteres de un solo byte y de varios bytes y convertir entre conjuntos de caracteres. Las sesiones de cliente pueden utilizar conjuntos de caracteres de cliente que son diferentes del conjunto de caracteres de base de datos.

Considere el tamaño de los caracteres cuando se especifica la longitud de la columna para los tipos de datos de caracteres. Debe tener en cuenta este problema al estimar el espacio para tablas con columnas que contienen datos de caracteres.

La semántica de longitud de los tipos de datos de caracteres se puede medir en bytes o caracteres.

La semántica de bytes trata las cadenas como una secuencia de bytes. Este es el valor predeterminado para los tipos de datos de caracteres.

La semántica de caracteres trata las cadenas como una secuencia de caracteres. Un carácter es técnicamente un codepoint del conjunto de caracteres de la base de datos.

Para conjuntos de caracteres de byte único, las columnas definidas en la semántica de caracteres son básicamente las mismas que las definidas en la semántica de bytes. **La semántica de caracteres es útil para definir cadenas multibyte de anchura variable**; Reduce la complejidad al definir los requisitos reales de longitud para el almacenamiento de datos.

Por ejemplo, en una base de datos Unicode (UTF8), debe definir una columna `VARCHAR2` que puede almacenar hasta cinco caracteres chinos junto con cinco caracteres en inglés. En la semántica de bytes, esto requeriría (5 * 3 bytes) + (1 * 5 bytes) = 20 bytes; En la semántica de caracteres, la columna necesitaría 10 caracteres.

`VARCHAR2 (20 BYTE) y SUBSTRB (<cadena>, 1, 20)` utilizan semántica de bytes.

`VARCHAR2 (10 CHAR) y SUBSTR (<cadena>, 1, 10)` usan semántica de caracteres.

El parámetro `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` decide si una nueva columna de tipo de datos de carácter utiliza semántica de byte o de carácter. La longitud semántica predeterminada es byte. Si todas las columnas de tipos de datos de caracteres de una base de datos utilizan semántica de bytes (o todos usan semántica de caracteres), los usuarios no tienen que preocuparse acerca de qué columnas utilizan qué semántica. **Los calificativos `BYTE` y `CHAR` mostrados anteriormente deben evitarse cuando sea posible, ya que conducen a bases de datos semánticas mixtas**. En su lugar, el parámetro de inicialización `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` debe establecerse correctamente en el archivo de parámetros de servidor (`SPFILE`) o en el archivo de parámetros de inicialización y las columnas deben utilizar la semántica predeterminada.

## NCHAR y NVARCHAR2

`NCHAR` y `NVARCHAR2` **son tipos de datos Unicode que almacenan datos de caracteres Unicode**. El conjunto de caracteres de los tipos de datos `NCHAR` y `NVARCHAR2` sólo puede ser `AL16UTF16` o `UTF8` y se especifica en el momento de creación de la base de datos como el conjunto de caracteres nacional. `AL16UTF16` y `UTF8` son codificación Unicode.

El tipo de datos `NCHAR` almacena cadenas de caracteres de longitud fija que corresponden al conjunto de caracteres nacionales.

El tipo de datos `NVARCHAR2` almacena cadenas de caracteres de longitud variable.

Cuando crea una tabla con una columna `NCHAR` o `NVARCHAR2`, el tamaño máximo especificado siempre está en semántica de longitud de carácter. La semántica de longitud de caracteres es la semántica predeterminada y de longitud única para NCHAR o `NVARCHAR2`.

Por ejemplo, si el conjunto de caracteres nacionales es UTF8, la siguiente sentencia define la longitud máxima de byte de 90 bytes:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 NCHAR (30));
```

Esta instrucción crea una columna con longitud máxima de caracteres de 30. La longitud máxima de bytes es el múltiplo de la longitud máxima de caracteres y el número máximo de bytes en cada carácter.

La longitud máxima de una columna `NCHAR` es 2000 bytes. Puede contener hasta 2000 caracteres. Los datos reales están sujetos al límite de bytes máximo de 2000. Las dos restricciones de tamaño deben satisfacerse simultáneamente en tiempo de ejecución.

```
NVARCHAR2
```

La longitud máxima de una columna `NVARCHAR2` es de 4000 bytes. Puede contener hasta 4000 caracteres. Los datos reales están sujetos al límite de bytes máximo de 4000. Las dos restricciones de tamaño deben satisfacerse simultáneamente en tiempo de ejecución.

Ver también:
[Oracle Database Globalization Support Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/toc.htm) para obtener más información sobre los tipos de datos `NCHAR` y `NVARCHAR2`

### Uso de datos Unicode en la base de datos Oracle

Unicode es un esfuerzo por tener una codificación unificada de cada personaje en cada idioma conocido por el hombre. También proporciona una forma de representar personajes definidos de forma privada. Una columna de base de datos que almacena Unicode puede almacenar texto escrito en cualquier idioma.

Los usuarios de Oracle Database que implementan aplicaciones globalizadas tienen una gran necesidad de almacenar datos Unicode en Oracle Databases. Necesitan un tipo de datos que se garantiza que sea Unicode independientemente del conjunto de caracteres de la base de datos.

Oracle Database admite un tipo de datos Unicode fiable a través de `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2` y `NCLOB`. Estos tipos de datos están garantizados para codificación Unicode y siempre usan semántica de longitud de caracteres. Los conjuntos de caracteres utilizados por `NCHAR` / `NVARCHAR2` pueden ser `UTF8` o `AL16UTF16`, dependiendo del ajuste del juego de caracteres nacional cuando se crea la base de datos. Estos tipos de datos permiten que los datos de caracteres en Unicode se almacenen en una base de datos que puede o no utilizar Unicode como conjunto de caracteres de base de datos.

#### Conversión implícita de tipos

Además de todas las conversiones implícitas para `CHAR` / `VARCHAR2`, Oracle Database también admite la conversión implícita para `NCHAR` / NVARCHAR2. También se admite la conversión implícita entre `CHAR` / `VARCHAR2` y `NCHAR` / `NVARCHAR2`.

---

- Fuente: [Documentación de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1821)

Answer (score 0):

De manera muy concreta.

```
nvarchar: Te puede almacenar cuaquier tipo de datos UniCode.
varchar: La columna tiene una restriccion de 8 bits.
nvarchar2: La columna tiene un limite mayor a 4000 bits, y debes especificar
```

la longitud máxima que deseas. Hasta donde yo tengo conocimiento, Nvarchar2 solo es utilizado en Oracle. Una de las características, te permite un mayor numero de caracteres especiales.

Comment: Cadena de caracteres Unicode de longitud variable con size como máximo tamaño de longitud. El número de bytes que pueden ser hasta dos veces el tamaño de codificación AL16UTF16 y tres veces el tamaño de la codificación UTF8. **El tamaño máximo está determinado por la definición del juego de caracteres nacional, con un límite máximo de 4000 bytes**. Se debe especificar el size de NVARCHAR2.

Comment: Lo que esta en negrita  o entiendo lo que quiere decir.

Comment: Si entiendes la definición, para que preguntas?

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda "lo que está en negrita **o** entiendo lo que quiere decir"....simplemente le faltó una **n**

Comment: ahhhh entiendo entiendo, disculpa!

Comment: ¿Tienes la fuente oficial para decir que este tipo de dato es utilizado en SQL Server?

Comment: Efectivamente, rectifico mi respuesta. Yo me confundi con el tipo de dato datetime2, no ha sido implementado en SQL server, solo es tulizado en Oracle. Disculpas a todos.

Answer (score 0):

**char** es un tipo de datos de una longitud variable. Este es de tipo de dato ANSI. Los valores más cortos que el tamaño de la columna no están bien acolchado con el tamaño de la columna. Vale decir

```
Dato a guardar          Dato guardado        
char(5) = '';             _____
char(5) = 'a';            ____a 
char(5) = 'asdas';        asdas
```

( "_" considerese como espacio).

En este caso se guardan siempre esos 5 espacios.

**nvarchar** Esto a su vez limita el tamaño máximo de un VARCHAR a 8.000 bytes. NVARCHAR significa "casi" lo mismo, con la diferencia que se puede almacenar datos unicode, de ahí proviene la N (uNicode).

**varchar2** y **varchar** almacena cadenas de caracteres de longitud variable determinada por el (obligatorio). Su rango es de 1 a 4000 caracteres. Vale decir:

```
Dato a guardar              Dato Guardado
varchar(5) = '';            
varchar(5) = 'a';           a
varchar(5) = 'asdas';       asdas
varchar(5) = 'asdasa'; // Generará Error
```

Espero que te haya quedado mas claro con esto.

**NOTA:**

Considérese que en los distintos motores de bbdd tienen ciertas variaciones, pero en esencia funciona de este modo.

Por el momento, varchar y varchar2 son sinonimos.
**VARCHAR2** está reservada por Oracle para apoyar distinción entre NULL y cadena vacía, sin estar totalmente seguro la version 12c vendria incorporado ya. VARCHAR no distingue entre una NULL y cadena vacía, y nunca lo hará.

Si depende de cadena vacía y NULL es la misma cosa, se debe utilizar VARCHAR2.

Comment: Qué significa tu ejemplo en los `varchar`s?, deberías mostrar la diferencia entre el valor que insertas y el que queda almacenado

Comment: Buen punto. Editare aquello

Comment: Es una buena edición, pero estás confundido. `char` se comporta de esa forma, `varchar` no, de ahí el "var", que su largo es variable (a comparación de `char`, donde el largo es fijo y debe rellenar con espacios)

Comment: te agradezco por la aclaración :D

Comment: yo que unos de los tipos de datos sql development(https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms151817.aspx) hay uno que pongas lo que pongas ocupara todo, por ejemplo: tipoDeDatoNoSeCualEs(5): 'Dato'==> ___Dato, lo ocupa todo rellanando espacios a la izquierda y al final a la derecha el contenido de un byte ó character.